# How to get those values which didn't return any row in SELECT query while using IN function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Query:

SELECT Column1 FROM Table WHERE Column2 IN ('val1,'val2','val3',....'valn');

Now I want those values which didn't return any rows. Means those values which I have passed in IN functions but they are not present in my tables.

Sorry if I failed to make it clear :)

Comment: queries can't return data that isn't present. but you could put them into a temp table and do a join against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.f FROM
(SELECT 'val1' as f
UNION ALL
SELECT 'val2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'val3') x
LEFT JOIN Table t ON x.f = t.Column2
WHERE t.Column2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
$have_values = array('val1','val2'..... 'valn');
$i=0;
$have_values_string=""; 
foreach($have_values as $var => $val)
{
$have_values_string.="'".$val."'";
if($i!=count($have_values)-1) {  $have_values_string.=",";}
$i++;
}

//now querying..
$sql=SELECT Column1 , Column2 FROM Table WHERE Column2 IN ('val1,'val2','val3',....'valn');
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$found_values[$row[0]]=$row[1];
}

$not_found_values=array_diff($have_values, $found_values);
```